# $n$ i.i.d variable $P[x_i=1]=P[x_i=-1]=1/2$, denote $Y_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \prod_{j=0}^i x_{k-j}^{\binom ij}$, what is $E[(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)^4]$?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

For example when $n=3$, there are $3$ random variable $x_0,x_1,x_2$, and $Y_1 = x_0$, $Y_2 = x_1 + x_0x_1$, $Y_3 = x_2 + x_1x_2 + x_0x_1^2 x_2$. We can write these in a matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\ x_0x_1 & x_1x_2 &  \\ x_0x_1^2x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

denote $a_{i,j}$ is the $i$-th row $j-$th column element of this matrix, then $a_{i,j}=a_{i-1,j}\times a_{i-1,j+1}$.

Now I have an $\Theta(n^4)$ time complexity algorithm: consider
$$E \left [\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i^{t_i} \right]$$
equals $1$ if and only if all $t_i$ are even, else it equals zero. So we can expand $(Y_1+\cdots +Y_n)^2$ then replace all $x_i^t$ to $x_i^{t \bmod 2}$ of it. At last the square sum of its coefficient is answer.

How can I solve it faster? Or does answer has a closed-form?

(annex) answer of $n \in \left\{ 1,\cdots,60\right\}$ (not found on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+21%2C+168%2C+664%2C+1725&language=english&go=Search)):

$1, 21, 168, 664, 1725, 3585, 6520, 10656, 16353, 23917, 33672, 45816, 60733, 78657, 99840, 124552, 153369, 186741, 225136, 268896, 318525, 374401, 436920, 506496, 583729, 669069, 762984, 865960, 978501, 1101129, 1234384, 1378824, 1535385, 1704805, 1887840, 2085120, 2297437, 2525457, 2769864, 3031360, 3310809, 3608949, 3926536, 4264344, 4623165, 5003809, 5407104, 5833896, 6285217, 6761949, 7264992, 7795264, 8353701, 8941257, 9558904, 10207632, 10888449, 11602381, 12350472, 13133784$